# Python Errors and Exceptions with TkInter

Tags: python, validation, tkinter

I am trying to program a TkInter GUI. I want to create an Entry which allows only Float Numbers which are less than 1000.

I am working with `try` and `except` method and my problem is that the code which is tested by the try-method is not executed but rather tested for ValueErrors.

Is there a way to execute the code between try and exception?

Thanks

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class MyOwnEntry:

    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = StringVar()
        self.variable.trace("w", self.Validation)
        self.MyOwnEntry = Entry(root, textvariable = self.variable)
        self.MyOwnEntry.pack()

    def Validation(self,*args):
        self.newvar = self.variable.get()
        try:
            if isinstance(float(self.newvar),float): 
                return self.newvar
            elif float(self.newvar)<1000:
                self.newvar = self.newvar[:-1]
                self.variable.set(self.newvar)
            else:
                self.newvar = self.newvar[:-1]
                self.variable.set(self.newvar)
        except ValueError:
            self.newvar = self.newvar[:-1]
            self.variable.set(self.newvar)




Input1 = MyOwnEntry()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there any error that is happening ? Is it getting caught in ```except``` clause? If so then probably there is a ValueError.
If you want to return the ```self.newvar``` then you should return it at the end of try except. You are only returning the value after the if condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create an Entry which allows only Float Numbers which are less than 1000.

You probably don't need the first condition if that ^ is what you want because it just returns `self.newvar` if the value is float but you also need to check if it's less than 1000

```
    def Validation(self, *args):
        self.newvar = self.variable.get()
        try:
            if isinstance(self.newvar,float) and self.newvar < 1000:
                self.newvar = self.newvar[:-1]
                self.variable.set(self.newvar)
            else:
                self.newvar = self.newvar[:-1]
                self.variable.set(self.newvar)
        except ValueError:
            self.newvar = self.newvar[:-1]
            self.variable.set(self.newvar)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use self.newvar[:-1] and the cursor is not at end ,then your last digit will be removed.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class MyOwnEntry:

    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = StringVar()
        self.variable.trace("w", self.Validation)
        self.MyOwnEntry = Entry(root, textvariable = self.variable)
        self.MyOwnEntry.pack()
        self.oldvar=0

    def isfloat(self,value):
      try:
        float(value)
        return True
      except ValueError:
        return False

    def Validation(self,*args):
        self.newvar = self.variable.get()
        if self.newvar:
            if not (self.isfloat(self.newvar) and float(self.newvar)<1000):
                self.newvar = self.oldvar
                self.variable.set(self.newvar)
            self.oldvar=self.newvar


Input1 = MyOwnEntry()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Amir this version works well for me

```
class MyOwnEntry:

    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = StringVar()
        self.variable.trace("w", self.Validation)
        self.MyOwnEntry = Entry(root, textvariable = self.variable)
        self.MyOwnEntry.pack()

    def Validation(self, *args):
        self.newvar = self.variable.get()
        try:
            if float(self.newvar) < 1000:
                return self.newvar
            else:
                self.newvar = self.newvar[:-1]
                self.variable.set(self.newvar)
        except ValueError:
            self.newvar = self.newvar[:-1]
            self.variable.set(self.newvar)
```

Comment: sure. Could you tell me how to acess the attribute newvar globally?
Input1.Validation.newvar is not working

Comment: I believe it's present in self.variable not validation. 
You should try input1.variable